# Counting two values together in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counting

I'm working on a function where I need to count how many times the combination of a country name and type of artwork appear together in the values of a dictionary and return the total count. I think I'm close but I'm having issues.

Example Dictionary:

```
{'V':[("Self-Portrait",1500,20.0,30.0,"oil paint","Italy")],
 'B':[("Self-Portrait",1500,20.0,20.0,"oil paint","Italy")],
 'K':[("Self-Portrait-1",1500,10.0,20.0,"oil paint","Netherlands"),("Self-Portrait-2",1510,10.0,20.0,"oil paint","Netherlands"),("Self-Portrait-3",1505,10.0,20.0,"oil paint","USA")],
 'M':[("Self-Portrait-1",1800,20.0,15.0,"oil paint","USA"),("Self-Portrait-2",1801,10.0,30.0,"oil paint","France")]
        }
```

In the above dictionary if I was counting for the number of times "oil paint" and "Italy appeared together in values it would return

```
count_appearances(dictionary4(),'oil paint','Italy')

#This should return "2"
```

This is the code I have so far. It is currently returning None for count and I'm not sure why

```
def count_media_in_country(db, media, country): 
    count = 0
    for key in db:
        for record in db[key]:
            if media and country == True:
                count += 1
            elif media and country == False:
                count += 0
                return count
```

Comment: How do you call `count_media_in_country()`? also `return count` should not be located inside the `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what you need:

```
def count_media_in_country(db, media, country):
    count = 0
    for value in db.values():
        for record in value:
            if record[4] == media and record[5] == country:
                count += 1
    return count # return statement should be after for loop (in this case)
```

`if media and country == True:` actually checks if `media` and `country` strings are not `None` and are not empty (you don't need that).

`count += 0` does not do anything (obviously)

```
if statement == True:
    # something
elif statement == False:
    # something
```

better way to write this is:

```
if statement:
    # something
else:
    # something
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_media_in_country(db, media, country): 
    count = 0
    for key in db:
        for record in db[key]:
            if media in record and country in record:
                count += 1
    return count
```

Your `elif` block is returning prematurely.  Also, you have to check list membership for each item separately, using the `in` keyword.